# kill process and its sub/co-processes by getting their parent pid by python script

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, kill-process

i am using MULTIPROCESSING to find my requirement.
And when that runs i am getting a pid(may be parent! i don't know what to call that) then co processes with their own pid and reference id of first process.

Now i need to kill all those processes BY ONLY KILLING THE FIRST PROCESS then which will be the best way to do that. THAT ALSO IN PYTHONIC WAY.

Scenario is like

```
  ps -ef |grep py
```

i am getting

```
  2222 0001 first.py  #0001 is os process
  4323 2222 second.py
  4324 2222 third.cgi
  4324 2222 fourth.py
  4325 2222 fifth.cgi
  4326 2222 sixth.py

  2223 0001 newfirst.py    ############new first process from another script started
  4327 2223 newsecond.cgi
  4328 2223 newthird.py
  4329 2223 newfourth.cgi
```

now i am killing process by (when a stop button is pressed)

```
 kill -6 2222   ###from terminal
```

then only first.py is getting killed and the remaining co-processes still running. Of course i can kill other processes from terminal,,but i want to do it in a more pythonic way(by running a script which will trigger when someone press a STOP button form front-end designed to run .py files  )

Now how can i kill all those co-process as soon as i kill first.py (as i don't want its co's to run anymore) but the other newfirst.py and its co's should not get disturbed.

what i come up to is this far

```
import os
pid = os.getpid()   
os.system('kill -9 ' + pid)
```

so how to filter out co-processes from that first process id 2222 and kill them.

i have also tried using psutil,but passing name after name to kill is not very convincing.

I have checked subprocess.popen method but failed and now  i am out of logic,please suggest.

If any other info is needed,please do comment.

Comment: To kill a process group with a signal `os.killpg(pgid, sig)` can be used. In your case `os.killpg(pid, 9)`

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I am not able to understand; however I am assuming that you have process id handy e.g. in your example, you have process id 2222. Then you can try this:

```
#Assuming you have parent_pid i.e. from your example you have 2222
pname = psutil.Process(parent_pid)
cpid = pname.get_children(recursive=True)
for pid in cpid:
    os.kill(pid.pid, signal_num) #signal_num is the signal you want to send i.e. 9 as per your example
```

Please take care of exception handling e.g. check if process/child-process exist before you kill it etc using `try - except` block.